# Participant number

Tags: code-golf, math

A math Olympiad will be held, and participants are being registered. The highest number of participants is 100. Each participant is given an ID number. It is given in a sequence like \$100, 97, 94, 91, 88, ...., 1\$, and when the first sequence is over, then \$99, 96, 93, 90, 87, ...., 3\$ sequence and so on.

Let's assume one of the participant's ID number is \$k\$ and he/she is the \$n^{th}\$ participant. Given the value of \$k\$, return the value of \$n\$.

**Test Cases**

```
59 -> 81
89 -> 71
16 -> 29
26 -> 92
63 -> 47
45 -> 53
91 -> 4
18 -> 62
19 -> 28
```

There will be no leading zero in input. Standard   loopholes apply, shortest code wins. In output there can be trailing whitespace.

Comment: Can you specify how this sequence works? Also this would work better under standard [tag:sequence] rules in my opinion.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms it might be too easy in sequence rules I think

Comment: I doubt it. It's very easy anyway.

Comment: can we take ids from 0...99 instead of 1...100?

Comment: @Jonah no you can't

Comment: These test cases are awful. They are extremely inconvenient for testing and there is a duplicate. Did you generate them randomly?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Yes 

Comment: Just so we're absolutely clear here, from what I can infer the third sequence id the final one and goes `98,95,...,2`? Because if not then you need to specify it in the description.

Comment: May I output as 0-indexed?

Comment: 2 -> 100 should definitely be a test case (since it catches an edge-case if using a mod 100).

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 23 bytes

```python
lambda n:1-199*~n/3%~99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc3BDoIwDIDhs3uKXkw2U6MdAhvJnkQ9YAQl0UIGFy@8@txm4u3r8rebPstzZB16dwmv9n27t8AN7cna3cqHYrtaG5ZuXmZwcJalRTCkEKSJqrOoQtA2SUdZnVQVCKc66VQilEWSpfiWFwxClTOKR7RRV9GPHhjBw8CQf2vEZvIDL9BLVs55IfIofmXKfMuPThLSkdS/Zkx9@AI)

I kind-of just tried stuff until I got something that worked.

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>11</s></sup> 9 bytes

```
€ΣTC3ṫ100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTmnOLQ5yNH@5cbWhg8P8/AA) or [Verify all tests](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9odXNr/20oUysoKyIgLT4gInPigoFyKSnCtv/igqzOo1RDM@G5qzEwMP///zU5Cjg5CjE2CjI2CjYzCjQ1CjkxCjE4CjE5)

-2 bytes, borrowing Unrelated String's idea.

### Explanation

```
€ΣTC3ṫ100
     ṫ100 [100..1]
   C3     slices of 3
  T       transpose
 Σ        join
€         index of input
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

Some magic formula after a bit of trial and error.

```python
lambda n:~-~n%3*33+34-~-n/3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctNCoMwEAXg/ZxiNkVtTUsSfxIhPUmhpLRiQGOwEenGq6cmq/mY9577@WG2LPTqEUY9vd4abbeT3Z74mfMLr8hO7I2HbTDjB2kHaKwrcV69Q4WTdrmxvsRFb88jWH1eXL9uND7PkNwxKwpAtxwV7I@iK1CptA21jLmgIBJaCrSJYBJYgmTQ8IiqhaqOqDlImj5ARbwNA5rWTPwB)

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>33</s> 20 bytes

*Thanks to @tsh for -13*

```js
n=>101+~n%3*33-n/3|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/hfllikkG77P8/WztDAULsuT9VYy9hYN0/fuMbgf0FRZl6JRrqGqaWmpoK@voKFIRdMyAIqZI4QMjSDCBlZwoWMoEKWRnAhM2OIkIk5PlUmphAhU2O4kKUhUAisE2GjBUSVGUKjIdRdRhb/AQ)

**Old:**

```js
n=>(n=100-n)%3*33+n/3+1+!!(n%3)|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc69DsIgFAXg3aegQxOQNPzcQmHAdyEOTR1uGmw6@e5oBGFz/XJOznnEMz7vaduP6XT5jImsIWO4UQxKygnZCFcAjgK44sNAcQT2knlPGx50pcYzRoQgTl1@5CotnZQtpH0jXcnrRhYKzcu/1GwKGWjk1Ye@zb7oSsr2oqq/tMtv)

I don't know why this works. Don't question it.

Comment: Do you need |0 at the end?

Comment: After some math simplify: Maybe `n=>101+~n%3*33-n/3|0`

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ȷ2RUs3ZFi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///EdqOg0GLjKLfM/4fbHzWtifz/39RSx8JSx9BMx8hMx8xYx8RUx9JQx9BCx9ASAA)

```
   U         Reverse
  R          the inclusive range from 1 to
ȷ2           100.
    s3       Split it into slices of length 3,
      Z      zip the slices,
       F     flatten the columns,
        i    and find the index of the input in the resulting list.
```

Comment: Right, idk how I didn't think of using zip. I was thinking it'd be convenient if there were a way to take each block of three and then go through them column-wise...

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>28 27 26</sup> 24 bytes

```
(_,;(</.~3|])i._100)i.<:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NeJ1rDVs9PXqjGtiNTP14g0NDICUjdV/Ta7U5Ix8BQtDBVuFNAVTSwjXHMK1gHKNLMFcQzMI19IIzDWCck3MwVwzY6yypsZgrokpVDGYZ2kI4ZlB1BpaQO2xgHAtuf4DAA)

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to Bubbler</sup>

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NeJ1rDVs9PXqjGtiNTP14g0NDICUjdV/Ta7U5Ix8BQtDBVuFNAVTSwjXHMK1gHKNLMFcQzMI19IIzDWCck3MwVwzY6yypsZgrokpVDGYZ2kI4ZlB1BpaQO2xgHAtuf4DAA) using parenthesized noun expression.

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), <s>30</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
ceil(mod(67.1-101\frac n3,100))
```

[Try it here!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fdsckgc0hs)

*+2 bytes to account for edge case at 2*
*-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan!*

Comment: @JonathanAllan well, darn. I've always thought there should be an equivalent to \$\mod n\$ where multiples of \$n\$ go to \$n\$ instead of \$0\$, but no such operation exists... this workaround will have to do.

Comment: @JonathanAllan brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 23 bytes

```
p(n)=-n\3+(1-n)%3*33+35
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxDoAwCAXQ3XuYtDYdgFJh6E1cnIxLQ7x/UmF7@fyP3d9bH1vL0syjzotKgjrzTgdRIY4Dax5DYLMkoTME3YXqwpCiq5Orna7GLiaXQmQxEEePGsQTlPUD)

2 more bytes saved thanks to Dominic van Essen

Comment: Nice!  Looks like you can swap ```-n+1``` for ```n-1``` to [save 1 byte](https://tio.run/##Fcy9CoAwDATg3fcQUkUwTX@SoW/i4iQupfj@UC/bx@Uu4/7e4xlzDuqhEfHRwyqb2c5nhi/xU7bQmvIySF3VxQWKBkWXRagIlCqUMpQFMvbMBwoUr7E/iTp/)...

Comment: No, I want a function f: f=(0,1,2) for n=(100,99,98). To do that I need to reverse the results given by n%3, making the results (2,0,1) instead of (1,0,2) and cycle them to the right, giving (0,1,2). But I clearly should have done (1-n) instead of (-n+1), is it too late to fix it?

Comment: You're right: that was a typo by me.  Of course not too late to fix it - many of us 'fix' our answers continuously (look at all the crossed-out previous byte scores)!  Just click 'edit' below the post.  If you like (there's no requirement), you can leave the old score of 26 crossed out by surrounding it with ```<s>``` & ```</s>```...

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also: if you rearrange by pre-dividing ```99``` and ```105``` by 3, you'll save [2 more bytes](https://tio.run/##FcwxDoAwCAXQ3XuYtDYdgFJh6E1cnIxLQ7x/UmF7@fyP3d9bH1vL0swjQZ15p4OoEJc6L4oDax5DYLMkoTME3YXqwpCiq5Orna7GLiaXQmQxEEePGsQTlPUD) (and end-up with the same formula that [I used](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224093/95126), but arriving by a different route!)...

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
101ḶUẋ3m3ḟ0i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QwPDhjm2hD3d1G@caP9wx3yDz/@H2R01r/v83tdSxsNQxNNMxMtMxMwaRJqY6loY6hhY6hpYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 34 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to ovs!

```python
lambda a:101-round(-~a%3*33.3+a/3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRytDAULcovzQvRUO3LlHVWMvYWM9YO1HfWPN/Wn6RQqZCZp5CUWJeeqqGoQ5QqaYVF2dBUWZeiUamTppGpqbmfwA)

Comment: `[1,2,0][a%3]` can be golfed to `-~a%3*` and `int(...+.5)` is the same as `round(...)`. [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRytDAULcovzQvRUO3LlHVWMvYWM9YO1HfWPN/Wn6RQqZCZp5CUWJeeqqGoQ5QqaYVF2dBUWZeiUamTppGpqbmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s><sup>11</sup></s> 10 bytes

*Thanks to @Razetime for -1 byte by writing `199` as `⁺b`.*

```
ꜝ⁺b*3ḭ₁N%⌐
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%EA%9C%9D199*3%E1%B8%AD%E2%82%81N%25%E2%8C%90&inputs=16&header=&footer=)

Vyxal port of [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224040/101522), with a bit of extra golfing.

Explanation:

````
            # Note: 'X' denotes current value.

            # Implicit input
ꜝ           # ( X + 1 ) * -1
 ⁺b*        # X * 199
    3ḭ      # X // 3
      ₁N%   # X % -100
         ⌐  # 1 - X
            # Implicit output
```
````

Comment: [10 bytes using `⁺b` for `199`](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%EA%9C%9D%E2%81%BAb*3%E1%B8%AD%E2%82%81N%25%E2%8C%90&inputs=16&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
Ｉ⊕÷﹪⁻²⁰¹×¹⁰¹Ｎ³⁰⁰¦³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYxDoMwDADArzA6EkihhaljuzCAOvQDaWIJS4lTJQ7fd2E5nd9d8dlF1XchFni6KrCwL5iQBcN5edFBAWHNocUMK3GrcLNj330oYYXx6sK/JltLXyxgjOm7u7WX581DdZp1OOIf) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Implements the formula `n=1+(201-101*k)%300/3`, which I found through trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```
Lõ Ôó3 c aU Ä
Lõ            // Create the range [1..100],
   Ô          // reverse it and
    ó3        // group by every third item.
       c      // Flatten the result, then
         aU Ä // return the index of input plus one.
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=TPUg1PMzIGMgYVUgxA==&input=MTk=)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 30 bytes

```r
k=scan();35+-k%/%3+33*(1-k)%%3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3BCoQgEAbgu08xEIJuxKZm6S7tu0QZhGCQdYp9djdDb3saPv6Zf7YQbO/HwRH6FrKsLH5iUQrxIKyyFGMRWF0jVMBk5sUZGDzMhxv3ZXWwr7Ad1zB@h3Hwxr/QMvU5Jpae6G8l@l57RGoKBVQfUCxSZXY3WZvIdSTP1DyyFYlNF9nIRCkiNcvp3aSS2vuU5T9cofAD)

There are already 12 other answers in various languages before I managed to post this, and - amazingly for what seems such a simple task - they mostly seem to use different formulas/strategies to each other, and all appear to be different to this one.

I suspect this means that if I go-through all the other approaches, I'll find that at least some of them will turn-out to be golfier than this one, though...

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn) `-IF`, [12 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

Found a few bugs while writing this, lol. This is 0-indexed (e.g. 59 -> 80), I'm not sure if that's okay so I can change the answer if it isn't (somebody asked in the comments but there was no response).

```
&»¨)¢►†3K1v&
```

## Explained

Unpacked: `e2.~::%3-1& .@`

I see some answers explain like this:

```
  e2.~    Descending range from 100 to 1
  ::%3-1  Sort in chunks of 3
  & .@    Bind the transpose operator to the output
```

And others like this:

```
    e2   1 * 10 ^ 2 = 100
  .~     Descending range
::       Sort adjacently while the right is truthy
      _    The currently value
    %      Modulo
      3    Three
  -        Minus
    1      One
&        Bind
  .@     The transpose operation
```

So I might as well include both. Either way, there is an implicit `:_` and `:i` surrounding the program. The space in `& .@` is required because `&.` is a symbol in the language already. I admit the flags are a bit cheaty, so for anybody curious this would be `15 bytes` without the two flags.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
тLR3ôζ˜þIk>
```

Port of [*@UnrelatedString*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224026/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YpNPkPHhLee2nZ5zeJ9ntt3//6aWAA) or [verify the entire sequence](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X@xydXPXknhUdskBSV7IM8nyPjwlnPbTs85vM8v2@6/zn8A).

Alternatively, a port of [*@xnor*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224040/52210) (which only works in the legacy version of 05AB1E due to the negative modulo) would be 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) as well:

```
$±Ƶ$*3÷т(%-
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f5dDGY1tVtIwPb7/YpKGq@/@/qSUA) or [verify the entire sequence](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/X@xyc3PzsVeSeFR2yQFJfv/hsWHNh7bqqJlfHj7xSYNVd3/Ov8B).

**Explanation:**

```python
тLR          # Push a list in the range [100,1]
   3ô        # Split it into parts of size 3
     ζ       # Zip/transpose the list, using a space as filler
      ˜      # Flatten this list of triplets
       þ     # Remove the spaces by only leaving digits
        Ik   # Get the (0-based) index of the input in this list
          >  # Increase it by 1 to make it a 1-based index
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)

$            # Push 1 and the input
 ±           # Get the Bitwise-NOT of that: -input-1
  Ƶ$*        # Multiply it by 199
     3÷      # Integer-divide it by 3
       т(%   # Modulo -100
$         -  # Subtract it from the 1 we pushed at the start
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ƶ$` is `199`.